# Rvest: ! `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute

Tags: r, forms, action, rvest

I wish to login to WSJ with rvest, but I always get the following error:
"! `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute". Any idea how to solve it?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

s <- session("https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login-page?op=localop&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid%20tags%20prts%20suuid%20updated_at&client_id=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=d3dc54f1-fe5e-48e9-bd51-8a68fad0149a&ui_locales=en-us-x-wsj-223-2&mars=-1&ns=prod%2Faccounts-wsj&state=uOiEi-3gL2l96PQr.7-1So7BT-lU63MJRKIYfRsAkhTy_-CPhVwqRvddS3VM&protocol=oauth2&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO#!/signin")

form <- read_html(s) |> 
  html_form() |> 
  first() |> 
  html_form_set(
    username = "xxx",
    password = "xxx",
  )

html_form_submit(s, form)
```

Answer (score 0):

`html_form_submit()` takes a form as its first input.  Try

```
read_html(s) |> 
  html_form() |> 
  first() |> 
  html_form_set(
    username = "xxx",
    password = "xxx",
  ) |>
  html_form_submit()
```